# Flatten a Set of Future List into one Future List

Tags: scala

I'm trying to call `persistenceService.find()` returning a `Future[List[Scan]]` foreach email passed to my method `findByEmails` which should return the merged `Future[List[Scan]]` of every calls to `persistenceService.find()`

So currently, I have this:

```
def findByEmails(emails: Set[String]): Future[List[Scan]] = {
    val results: Set[Future[List[Scan]]] = emails.map(email => persistenceService.find("report.commitsStats.contributors." + email -> BSONDocument("$exists" -> true)))
}
```

I can't figure out how to merge each `Future[List[Scan]]` in the `results` Set so my method return one `Future[List[Scan]]`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Future.sequence` to combine a list of futures, then a flatten on the list should be enough, the code might look similar to this not tested code:

```
def f(str: String): Future[List[Scan]] = ???

def g(emails: List[String]): Future[List[Scan] = {
  val futures: List[Future[list[Scan]]] = emails.map(f)
  val futureListList: Future[List[List[Scan]] = Future.sequence(futures)
  futureListList.map(_.flatten)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to also convert my Set to a list since without it final returned type was Future[Set[Scan]]].